# Method Start Delay

Tags: java, android

I was wandering is their anyway to delay a methods start when it is called. I have an update method and I wanted to add a 3 second delay before it is started.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should describe why you need to do that. whenever you are considering adding a "sleep" or "delay" into your code, it's almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I needed to stop the sprites from being created so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a good job for a Handler. Create a handler in your activity, and then use it to post a runnable (which should contain your code) :

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // Your code goes here...
    }
}, 3000); // Delay by 3000ms
```

More information on handlers in the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, I didn't know I could use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of a callback or a straight pause?

You can use Thread.sleep() to introduce a delay, however if your application is single threaded this will introduce a delay to your entire application.

Otherwise, you may want to spawn a thread that executes this method and the thread can sleep for three seconds before proceeding or use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to execute a runnable with a 3 second delay initial delay.

Comment: It is single threaded and to put the contents inside of the update method inside of its own thread would cause some issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a Thread.sleep() command as seen here:

```
try{
  Thread.sleep(4000);
}  catch (InterruptedException ie)
```